# Angular scope not updating when passed in object to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I have a controller function which is called on double click of an item in an ng repeat:

```
$scope.likeUpdate = function(update) {
    $http.post( $rootScope.apiURL + 'likeupdate', {
        update_id : update.data.id,
        user_id : $rootScope.currentUser.id
    }).success(function(result, response){
        update.data.does_like = result[0][0].does_like;
        console.log(result[0][0].does_like);
    });
}
```

This, should to me, change on my Ionic app and update on the screen the 'does_like' value.

However, it doesn't.

Here is my ng repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="update in updates" class="custom-card">
    <div ng-show="{{update.image}}" class="image">
        <img on-double-tap="likeUpdate({{update.data.id}})" class="full-image" ng-src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/{{update.image.name}}" imageonload>
    </div>
    {{ update.data.does_like }}
</div>
```

On page load, the update.data.does_like correctly shows what I need, and after page refresh will show what It should. But in my code its not updating live on the success callback.

The console log shows the correct output.

P.S I know doing result[0][0] isn't good, shall be working on structure soon.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: **Specifically** what version? The `success` callback on the `$http` promise has been deprecated recently

Comment: I think you simply need to change your `on-double-tap` expression to `likeUpdate(update)`. I'm not actually sure how you were not getting other errors passing `{{update.data.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
update is a local variable to the function.
```

try

```
$scope.updates = result[0];
```

But your structure looks off.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `likeUpdate` to change the `data.does_like` property of the `update` in question, you should pass the `update` to it instead of whatever `{{update.data.id}}` resolves to, ie

```
<img on-double-tap="likeUpdate(update)" ...
```

While we're making changes, you should remove the deprecated `success` method

```
$scope.likeUpdate = function(update) {
    $http.post($rootScope.apiURL + 'likeupdate', {
        update_id : update.data.id,
        user_id : $rootScope.currentUser.id
    }).then(function(response) {
        update.data.does_like = response.data[0][0].does_like;
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks, still not updating on my screen for some reason, anything else it could be? Even if I do update = 'test' nothing happens